# Can you compile and run a c++ file in the Linux terminal?

Tags: c++, terminal, raspberry-pi, raspbian

I am coding on a Raspberry Pi, and I just learned C++,and I want to continue coding in it. I am using the Raspbian OS. I can't download xCode, as it is humongous, and the Raspberry Pi would break. In CodeCademy, it teaches you to compile and run the programs using `g++` and `./a.out`. Is there any way to do that in the terminal of the Raspberry Pi?

Comment: `g++ file.cpp && ./a.out`?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes, but you have to install a C++ compiler first.  As root, run `apt-get update && apt-get install g++`.  Then you can run `g++` as usual.